# Can anybody help me with an issue regarding checking to see if an array of strings exist within a string?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, object, foreach

What I am doing is looping through an **object** of tweets, and within each iteration I am checking to see if the tweet contains any words stored in an **array**.

This example shows the preg_match, however I am having the same issue if I use strpos() or stripos() instead.

**Here is the function:**

```
function contains($tweet, $words) {
   $count = 0;
   foreach($words as $word) {
       if (preg_match('/'.$word.'/',$tweet)) {
           $count++;
       }
   }

    return $count;
}
```

The problem is that it's not going through the **if** statement unless I hard code in a word. $word DOES contain the correct values and are definitely strings as I have tried echoing and var_dumping out the value in the loop.

**Usage:**

```
$results = $twitter->request('search/tweets', 'GET', $parameters);
$negative_words = file("negative-words.txt");

foreach($results->statuses as $tweet) {
    echo contains($tweet->text, $negative_words);
}
```

I have tried searching around and tried many different approached and nothing has worked yet. Does anybody know what the issue might be?

Comment: Can you show `$tweet` and `$words`?

Comment: @chris85 Echoing out '$tweet' returns a string. '$words' is an array that takes words from a text file. Echoing out '$word' within the loop returns the correct word each time as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some SNEAKY carriage returns on the end of the strings returned by the list. The issue was resolved by removing them using str_replace().

Comment: You should be able to accommodate for that with a better regex. Post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

**Working example:**

```
<?php
    function contains($tweet, $words)
    {
        $count = 0;
        array_walk($words,function($word) use(&$count,$tweet){
            if(strpos($tweet,$word)!==false){
                $count++;
            }
        });
        return $count;
    }
```

Comment: I still have the same problem using this, if I replace '$word' with a hard coded word - it doesn't go through the if statement! :(

Comment: Could you please show sample of code where have you hardcoded it?